# Creating new <div> to hold twitch embed and assign twitch embed into it

Tags: javascript, html, twitch-api

Quick say, I am very very new to HTML and JS, I'm assuming there is a very simple solution that I am overlooking or misunderstanding.

I am trying to create a main container that will hold all my sub containers that will have the twitch embeds and a button alongside them.

The problem I am encountering is that it looks like there is only one container that the twitch embedded code looks for, which is "twitch-embed" and it seems that it must exist in the HTML before the HTML is loaded, otherwise the stream never loads and the rest of my code doesn't load.

Is there a way to load the  first while in the  section of my code? Or am I misunderstanding something from the twitch API and/or how JS HTML works?

```
<body style="background-color:#271e27">

<input style="background-color:#362e37", "color:#000000" type="search" id="twitchName" placeholder="Enter twitch name">
<button type="button" onclick="addEmbed(document.getElementById('twitchName').value)">watch</button>
<p id="test_input"></p>

<!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
<div id="twitch-embed"></div>
<!-- Intended container to hold the multiple streams -->
<!-- <div id="twitch-container"></div> -->

<!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
<script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("script initi");

  function addEmbed(channelName){
    console.log("starting function for " + channelName);
    var channelnameButtonID = channelName + "button"
    var channelnameStreamDivID = channelName + 'ID'

    console.log("creating button");
    var butt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    butt.id=channelnameButtonID;

    console.log("creating div");
    var newTwitchEmbed = document.createElement('div');
    newTwitchEmbed.id = "twitch-embed";

    console.log("creating embed");
    var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
      width: 284,
      height: 160,
      channel: channelName,
      layout: "video",
      parent: ["embed.example.com", "othersite.example.com"]
    });

    console.log('testing channel name button id')
    console.log(channelnameButtonID);

    console.log("creating button listener");
    butt.addEventListener('click',() => {
      console.log('click');
      // embed.remove();
      document.getElementById(channelnameButtonID).remove();
    })
    // document.getElementById("channelnameStreamDivID").appendChild();
    // action already performed via new twitch embed?
    console.log("appending button");
    document.getElementById("twitch-container").appendChild(butt);
    console.log("button appended");

    console.log("creating embed listener");
    embed.addEventListener(Twitch.Embed.VIDEO_READY, () => {
      var player = embed.getPlayer();
      player.setQuality("160p");
      player.setVolume("0.01");
      player.play();
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it just took me a few minutes to realize, sorry for wasting time here.

So I just forgot to add the newly created  into the "twitch-container" I created, since it wasn't really "existing" in the HTML until I appended the "twitch-embed" into the "twitch-container".